# KDE: Use window as desktop

Tags: kde

I want to, basically, embed dolphin in my desktop. So I set up some window-specific settings for dolphin#1, i.e. Keep Below, Maximize, Skip Taskbar. Now I want to set up a global shortcut that will take me to that window, either by minimizing all others temporarily (like Show Desktop) or by bringing it to the front. But, I haven't been able to find a way to do either of those. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of KDE's features is multiple desktops, plus some cool switching effects, like treating the desktops like faces of a cube that rotates to select a different desktop.  But it sounds like using multiple desktops would achieve what you're looking for.  It also avoids the situation of many application windows covering each other, and needing to do what you're asking about in the question to access what you want.

Multiple desktops is like having multiple monitors, each devoted to an activity that you want immediate access to, all set up and ready to use.  But instead of multiple monitors, the content of each monitor is selectable on a single monitor as a desktop.  Each desktop is a workspace that you can devote to whatever purpose you want.

For example, I spend a lot of time in Firefox with a lot of open tabs, and in Thunderbird with many email accounts and a calendar.  So I have each one full screen in its own desktop.  If I'm doing something in another desktop, like say working on a spreadsheet, and I want to copy and paste a lot of different snippets from the spreadsheet into an answer on Super User, I can right-click on the spreadsheet window and move it to the Firefox desktop.  Then I can see both simultaneously so it's easier to copy content between them.

The different distros sometimes organize the System Settings a little differently.  But `Workspace Behavior` is typically where you find `Virtual Desktops`, which is where you define how many virtual desktops you want.

There is typically already a widget installed to display icons for switching between desktops, but widgets are available for different styles and preferences of working with desktops.  They're easy to load and unload if you want to try different ones.  You can also use keyboard shortcuts to switch.

`Desktop Effects` is typically where you will find the System Settings for the neat stuff KDE lets you do with desktops.